# How do I access mshtml.HTMLDocument.frames on multiple threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, frames, mshtml, shdocvw

So, I have a main thread that captures an existing IE browser and saves the HTMLDocument in a variable.  I attached an event handler to the "onload" event of this document because I need a frame that is located inside it.  If I capture the frame in the main thread, everything is fine, but when the event is raised, I get an exception when I access the document:

```
For I = 0 To MyHTMLDocument.frames.length - 1
```

I have tried invoking the main thread, I tried making sure that the main document was fully loaded, but nothing seems to work.  I always get a "**Specified cast is not valid.**"

Putting **MyHTMLDocument.frames** into the Watch window in Visual Studio also gives the same exception "**Specified cast is not valid.**"  I'm not casting anything, am I?  Some websites suggested using `<STAThread()> _` which I tried for the heck, but to no avail.  I also tried `TryCast(MyHTMLDocument.frames, FramesCollection)`.

All I need to do is recapture a frame's document with a specific name when the document is refreshed.  I assume that it's a problem with threading, but invoking doesn't even work...  A funny thing is that I can access other things like Title, GetElementsByName, etc.  Just not the darn frames...

Comment: And what happens if you try to iterate that on the UI thread? Have you tried placing a breakpoint on the `For I = 0 ...` line and inspecting the `frames` collection/array?

Comment: The iteration works as expected from the UI thread.  No problems whatsoever.  It looks for the frame with the name that I want, casts it as an `IHTMLWindow2`, and I'm able to click an element located IN the frame.  But should the main document get reloaded, of course, I lose everything and have to get the handle again.  That's my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to get the collection via invocation. If you call `Me.Invoke()` you can get the return value from that as your collection. What .NET Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting 4.5.  What I ended up doing is creating a shared function with a name like `getFrame` that grabs all the components/elements as they are at the moment.  No need for Invokes.  It works.  I will leave the question open in case people have solutions.  At this point, it's more curiosity on WHY I was having the issue...  By the way, do you mean `Me` is in reference to the UI thread?

Comment: `Me` would be the current form, yes. -- Though you say you attach an event handler to the document's `OnLoad` event. Perhaps that is the issue (or part of it)? Load events are usually fired before the object is done rendering/showing.

Comment: Ahh... Now maybe that is it.  I did wait for the frame to load in a `Do...Until` loop, but I suppose when speaking about embedded frames, it doesn't work like I thought.  The page was actually loaded because I could physically see it in the IE window, but maybe it didn't captured the page before the frame was loaded?  I don't know enough about COM's to answer that.  I'll do some testing and see what I can come up with.  You might be right.

Comment: Otherwise try something like this for thread-safety: `Dim frames = Me.Invoke(Function() Return MyHTMLDocument.frames)`.

Comment: I had this same issue when running in a C# class project.  I created a Winforms project and ran the same code and all is well.

Comment: mshtml is STA thus expect its methods to be called from the same thread.